# How find the query difference between hibernate and running sql directly?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, time

I have query like:

```
 delete from tableA where fk in (select id from tableA where fk='somevalue'
 and tableA.date between date1 and date2)
```

When I run this query from TOAD it takes near 100ms. When I run using

```
                   session
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "delete ....")
                .setParameter("...")
                .setParameter("...")
                .setParameter("...")
                .executeUpdate();
```

It takes near 30 minutes
Really query deletes 0 rows. So may be there are some hibernate/oracle issues. How I can found them?
Thanks.

Comment: don't understand. Please more details. Subquery is need for criteria - which rows should be deleted. Does it create problem?

Comment: I'd suggest to enable Hibernate's query log as explained [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html) or [here](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2010/03/how-to-debug-hibernate-sql-queries-with-parameters/), because there shouldn't be such a difference when you're running native queries.

Comment: get the SQL through show sql property and run an explain plan on it. that'll give some clues towards optimisation. btw the query above looks odd, you dont need the "IN" clause... guess thats because you simplified for illustration...

Comment: Is `tableA` a typo in the sub-query?  Or are you really querying the same table twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably talking about the [hibernate.show_sql property from Hibernate configurations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html) (ctrl+f for "show_sql")

Setting this property to "true" will print the used SQLs to your standard output

Comment: Thanks. I have set show_sql to true. It is the same query as I have supposed. But it hungs for unknow reasons. I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of such a long time, the small overhead that hibernate may produce won't be noticed.

You can probably speed up the deletion by adding indexes in the `fk` and `date` columns ( a composite one may work well in this case ).

**UPDATE**
I'll elaborate a bit, to clarify why I suggest this.
Hibernate will have to resolve mappings  for the query executed (and in the case of a select statement it will have to create objects and fill them with results). In this case it doesn't look like this overhead will be important, as we are talking about 30 minutes of execution.

So the problem, probably lies somewhere else like :

- Network isues if executing TOAD and the java process from different machines
- Some difference between JDBC and OCI
- A bad translation of the query, which can be checked with the show_sql property. In this case **usually** there's something wrong with the mappings.

As there are not being any deletions as stated in the question and even with that the query takes 30 mins, that's why I suggested the index. It is true that it may slow deletions, but again, in this case no rows are deleted, so it takes 30 minutes to execute the subquery, not to do any deletions.

This answer may not solve the issue, but I honestly don't think it deserved a downvote.

Comment: As explained in the question, when executed in a tool his query is already pretty fast.  And adding indexes may even slow down deletions because they also have to be updated on deletion.

Comment: But the issue will not probably be hibernate as it has very little to do with a query like this one. Maybe then the difference is between jdbc and OCI, network issues if executing from different boxes .... What I wanted to state is that hibernate is probably not the reason.